# Intercom container empty for logged in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intercom

We are integrating intercom for our platform using the `intercom-rails` gem.
Here is the options enabled in our configuration file:

**config/intercom.rb**

```
IntercomRails.config do |config|
  app_id = MY_APP_ID
  config.app_id = ENV["INTERCOM_APP_ID"] || app_id
  config.enabled_environments = ["development", "production"]
  config.include_for_logged_out_users = true
end
```

The Intercom chat does appear for logged out users without any problem, but as soon as a user logs in, the chat disappears, and the containing div tag is empty:

```
<div data-reactroot="" class="intercom-app-container">
  <div class="intercom-app">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <!-- react-empty: 7 -->
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

If the user logs out, the chat does not appear on the landing anymore and I need to clear the cookies from the browser in order to make it appear again.

Anyone had a similar problem with integrating intercom?

**EDIT**

I found the problem eventually, thanks to a very, very small line at the bottom of the doc:

> Note that even after you’ve installed the code for logged-in users, the Intercom Messenger won’t appear for them until you’ve started a trial of Intercom Engage or Resolve.

And I only subscribed to Acquire.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem eventually, thanks to a very, very small line at the bottom of the doc:

> Note that even after you’ve installed the code for logged-in users, the Intercom Messenger won’t appear for them until you’ve started a trial of Intercom Engage or Resolve.

And I only subscribed to Acquire.